# How do I show a block in a region?

Tags: theming, blocks

All blocks in the *footer* region use a CSS grid system. I want to add a `<div>` with CSS attributes to each (custom) block in the footer. The code I have will show the blocks in the footer, but will give an error. Changing `{{ key }}` to `{{ key.content }}` is not helping. I am using Drupal 8.6.8.

The code that I am using in the page.html.twig template is the following.

```
{% for key in page.footer %}
    <div class="col col-4">
        {{ key }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Using that code, I get this error message.

> User error: "0" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Render\Element.php).

Comment: are you using the bootstrap theme ?
try {% for key, val in page.footer %}
{{ dump .. or knit val }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove array keys starting with '#':

```
{% for key, block in page.footer if key|first != '#' %}
    <div class="col col-4">
        {{ block }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```